# Dictionary value sorting

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary with tuples as keys (containing a string and an  int) and floats as values. An example:

```
first = {}
first['monkey', 1] = 130.0 
first['dog', 2] = 123.0-
first['cat', 3] = 130.0
first['cat', 4] = 130.0
first['mouse', 6] = 100.0
```

Now, I need to make a new dictionary, which has the original dictionary key's second element as 
it's key. The new dictionary's value should be the the place it stands if the keys were sorted. Added to this, there are two exceptions:

1. If two dicts have values that are equal, but have different strings in the key, the one with the lowest int in the key should be placed higher.
2. If two dicts have values that are equal, but have different ints in the key, they should be placed equal in the new dict and all get the same values.

So, the new dictionary should be as the following:

```
second[1] = 3
second[2] = 2
second[3] = 4
second[4] = 4
second[6] = 1
```

I know that it's ignorant to ask someone else to solve my problem without giving my  code for it. 
But i'm simply don't know how to approach the problem. I would be glad if you could provide me with an explanation how would you solve this problem , or even give me a pseudocode of the algorithm.

Comment: Learn something new everyday. Didn't know you could have a tuple for a dictionary key.

Comment: @Hoopdady tuples are immutable so it's OK

Comment: Is there supposed to be a - after first['dog', 2] = 123.0-

Comment: I also feel like I have the knowledge to solve this, I'm just not completely sure what's being asked.

Comment: Have to agree with Hoppdady. I had no idea the parentheses could be omitted when using a tuple for a key.

Comment: You wrote "1. If two dicts have values that are equal, but have different strings in the key...". What two dicts are you talking about?

Comment: If the key were sorted the way you describe (with the exceptions), what would the resulting order be for that data you have in `first`?

Comment: The resulting order is showed in a dictionary called 'second' in my example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import itertools as IT

first = {
    ('monkey',1): 130.0,
    ('dog',2): 123.0,
    ('cat', 3): 130.0,
    ('cat', 4): 130.0,
    ('mouse', 6): 100.0
    }

counter = 0
ordered = sorted(first, key = lambda k: (first[k], k[1], k[0]))

second = {}
for key, group in IT.groupby(ordered, first.__getitem__):
    # group = list(group)
    # print(key, group)
    # (100.0, [('mouse', 6)])
    # (123.0, [('dog', 2)])
    # (130.0, [('monkey', 1), ('cat', 3), ('cat', 4)])
    previous = None
    for name, num in group:
        if name != previous:
            counter += 1
        second[num] = counter
        previous = name

print(second)
```

yields

```
{1: 3, 2: 2, 3: 4, 4: 4, 6: 1}
```

---

**Explanation:**

The first step is to order the `(name, num)` keys of `first` according to the associated values. However, in case of ties, the `num` is used. If there is still a tie, the `name` is used to break the tie.

```
In [96]: ordered = sorted(first, key = lambda k: (first[k], k[1], k[0]))

In [97]: ordered
Out[97]: [('mouse', 6), ('dog', 2), ('monkey', 1), ('cat', 3), ('cat', 4)]
```

---

Next, we need to group the items in `ordered` since there are special rules when the value `first[k]` is the same. The grouping can be achieved using [itertools.groupby](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
In [99]: for key, group in IT.groupby(ordered, first.__getitem__):
   ....:     print(key, list(group))
   ....:     
   ....:     
(100.0, [('mouse', 6)])
(123.0, [('dog', 2)])
(130.0, [('monkey', 1), ('cat', 3), ('cat', 4)])
```

`itertools.groupby` is collecting the items in `ordered` into bunches according to the value of the key, `first.__getitem__(item)`. For example,

```
In [100]: first.__getitem__(('monkey', 1))
Out[100]: 130.0

In [101]: first.__getitem__(('cat', 3))
Out[101]: 130.0
```

`first.__getitem__(item)` is just a fancy way of writing `first[item]`. The reason why I use `first.__getitem__` is because `itertools.groupby` expects a function for its second argument, and `first.__getitem__` is the function that fits the bill.

---

Finally, we iterate through each group. Basically, we want to do this:

```
for name, num in group:
    counter += 1
    second[num] = counter
```

**except** that, when the names are equal, we do not want to advance the counter. So to check if the names are equal, it helps to store the previous name:

```
previous = None
for name, num in group:
    if name != previous:
        counter += 1
    ...
    previous = name
```

---

**Warning**: Note that rkd91's code and my code produce different answers for

```
first = {
    ('monkey',1): 130.0,
    ('dog',2): 123.0,
    ('cat', 3): 129.0,
    ('cat', 4): 130.0,
    ('mouse', 6): 100.0
    }
```

probably due to different interpretations of the specifications. I'll leave it to you do decide which is yielding the desired output.

@rdk91's code yields

```
{1: 4, 2: 2, 3: 5, 4: 3, 6: 1}
```

my code yields

```
{1: 4, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 5, 6: 1}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It's even more than i actally hoped to get. I'm sorry if i didn't explain my question clearly , it might be because English isn't my native language :d.

Answer (score 2):

1) Get a list of key-value tuples using `first_list = first.items()`

2) Create a [custom comparator function](http://icfun.blogspot.ca/2009/08/python-customize-sorting-with.html) that will sort the list according to your criteria.

3) Sort the list using `first_list.sort(comparator)`

4) Build your new dictionary from the sorted list.

Answer (score 1):

```
rob@rivertam:~/Programming$ cat sorter.py 
first = {}
first['monkey', 1] = 130.0
first['dog', 2] = 123.0
first['cat', 3] = 130.0
first['cat', 4] = 130.0
first['mouse', 6] = 100.0

# Get the keys of first, sorted by the value (ascending order), and then by the integer in the key (descending order) if two keys have the same value

s = sorted(first, key=lambda x: x[0])
s.reverse()
s = sorted(s, key=lambda x: first[x])

# Loop through these, and create a new list where the key is the integer in the old key, and the value is the position in the sorted order.

last_val = None
last = (None, None)
index = 0
new_dict = {}

for item in s:
    if not ((first[item] == last_val) and (item[1] != last[1]) and item[0] == last[0]):
        # When we have the same value, the same string but a different integer from the last key, consider it to be the same position in the sorted order.
        index += 1
    new_dict[item[1]] = index
    last_val = first[item]
    last = item

print new_dict
rob@rivertam:~/Programming$ python sorter.py 
{1: 3, 2: 2, 3: 4, 4: 4, 6: 1}
```